# Discord.js version 12 I can't ban a user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js version "12.1.1" and for this script 'banuser.js' I'm using a command handler.

For now I just want to ban the person, but I keep getting this error: 
**(node:30800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'banable' of undefined**

Cool features if this would work would be
unban + a timed ban -> that when I ban the person I can say 1/7 day ben or in hours...
But for now I want to make it work so I can ban people.

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {

      if (!message.mentions.users) return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');

      else {

          const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("696692048543088691");
          const member = message.mentions.members.first();
          let reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(' ');

          if (member.banable== false) return message.channel.send("That user cannot be baned!");

          else {

              if (!reason) reason = (`No reason provided.`);

              await member.send(`You have been baned from **${message.guild.name}** with the reason: **${reason}**`)
                  .catch(err => message.channel.send(`⚠ Unable to contact **${member}**.`));

              await member.ban(reason);

              const banEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                  // .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.iconURL()) -> kleine avatar
                  .setAuthor(member.user.avatarURL())
                  .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL())
                  .setAuthor(member.user.tag)
                  .setColor("#ee0000")
                  .setTimestamp()
                  .addField("Kicked By", message.author.tag)
                  .addField("Reason", reason);
                  // console.log(member.user.avatarURL('Heeft geen avatar'))

              await channel.send(banEmbed);

              console.log(`${message.author.tag} Baned ${member.user.tag} from '${message.guild.name}' with the reason: '${reason}'.`);

          }
      }
  } else {
      message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use the ban command.");
      return;
  }
}


module.exports.help = {
  name: "banuser"
}

/* module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") || !message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You don't have a permissions to do this.");
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();

    let member = message.guild.member(user);
    let reason = args.slice(22).join(" ");

    if (!user) return message.channel.send("Please mention the user.");
    if (user.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send("You can't ban yourself.");
    if (user.id === client.user.id) return message.channel.send("You can't ban me.");

    if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided";

    member.ban(reason).then(() => {
      message.channel.send(`Successfully banned **${user.tag}**`);
    }).catch(err => {
      message.reply("I was unable to ban the member.");
    })
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "banuser"
} */
```

This is my code so far

Comment: Should you be using `message.mentions.users.first()` instead of `message.mentions.members.first()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to replace `if (!message.mentions.users) return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');` with `if (!message.mentions.members) return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');`

Keep `const member = message.mentions.members.first();` as it is

And replace `member.banable` with `member.bannable`

Comment: Hi, Syntle ... The following error I have is
(node:17940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'banable' of undefined
Don't know if it's a typo or just the wrong command.

Comment: (node:36212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bannable' of undefined.
I changed it to `if (member.bannable == false) return message.channel.send("That user cannot be baned!");`

Comment: Did you use `message.mentions.users.first()` instead of `message.mentions.members.first()`?

Comment: My bad, `mentions.users` returns `User` which doesn't have the `bannable` property, use `mentions.members` returns `GuildMember` which does have the `bannable` property

Comment: how do I paste it?
Because I still get `'bannable not defiend` or I `get guildmember not defiend`.

Comment: I just edited my answer to guide you through everything and make it clearer